# Do I require an external server for my new mobile app? Only minimal text content to change within my app every couple of weeks

Tags: architecture, ios, server, appstore

I am about to submit my new app to the iOS App Store.

It's very simple. The app generates a random motivational quote and displays it onscreen. I have a database of 500 quotes now, stored in a plist file.

I will add more quotes bi-monthly, essentially just adding text to the existing plist file.

How should I approach this? Do I simply upload an amended plist file to my app within the 'backend' of the App Store? Would I have to submit a whole new build and version every time I amend the plist?

Or would I store this plist file on an external server and update that file? Am I able to link this updated plist file (on my external server) to the plist file within my existing app on the App Store?

What's my best approach?

I am really new to server side architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the short term, I think it makes perfect sense to update the app and submit a new build as needed - especially if "bi-monthly" means "every two months".

Eventually you will want to use a server.  You'll have better control of the data, you can correct errors, update much more often, and you'll also know how often people use your app.

Also, your users will not have to do anything to receive the new data.  A constantly updated app would be annoying.

By the way, storing the data on a server is a bit more complicated than simply dropping a plist file somewhere.  You'll probably need to learn more about [Web Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), and other ways apps communicate.

Comment: It doesn't *have to* be more complicated than dropping a file somewhere.